# How do I make a reference of a member of a struct that is inside of another struct?

Tags: c++, struct

I was trying this way:

```
(*point).member1.member2
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Impossible to answer without more details, and "doesn't work" is not a useful problem description.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make a reference of a member of a struct that is inside of another struct?

A bit unclear what you are asking for, but probably this is what you are trying to do:

```
struct A {
    struct B {
        void f() {}
    };
};

int main() {
    // pointer to member function of B
    // to which A::B::f is assigned
    void (A::B::*member)() = &A::B::f;

    A::B b{};

    // invoke member on b, equivalent to b.f()
    (b.*member)();
}
```

`member` is a pointer to a member of a class that is defined within another class, as mentioned in your title.
The last line of `main` just *invokes* the member for `b`. It's equivalent to `b.f();`.